# Cardboard unity sdk 0.7 CardboardAudio Renderer effect not found

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Recently I downloaded new version(0.7) of google cardboard sdk for unity. While importing package this error occurred, but from what I know it's like that for everybody(and from what i have been told  hitting cancel has no effect).[image]
(odmowa dostępu means acces denyed)

But then, after hitting cancel this error occurres:

`Effect CardboardAudio Renderer could not be found. Check that the project contains the correct native audio plugin libraries and that the importer settings are set up correctly.`
Effect CardboardAudio Renderer is effect of Master group of CardboardAudioMixer.

[image]

Before upgrading sdk to 0.7 everything worked fine.

Do you know how can I fix that? Any help is appreciated.

If something is not clear let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I removed that Effect ( see below ) then everything worked.

**Check lib:**
In my case the libaudiopluginvrunity.so file was copied over to my new project under Assets/Plugins/libs/armeabi-v7a/  .  You can check to see if it's missing:

In the project tab click on Assets->Plugins->Android->libs->armeabi-v7a then in the window immediately right of it doubleclick on the libaudiopluginvr.

This should bring up information in the Inspector showing the path for you to verify the plugin library is actually present in your project.

[image]

---

**Remove Effect:**

Top Menu->Window->Audio Mixer(Ctrl+8)
On the left side of the Audio Mixer tab look under Groups. I had only "Master"; select it.
The inspector window should then show a number of items including the offending Effect. Select the effect and press delete.

You'll note that if you select the "Add Effect" button that the "Cardboard Audio Renderer" effect is not one of the options.
I suspect the effect has been removed or renamed in the library?

[image]